# How to connect multiple usart to stm32 board

Tags: arm, stm32, usart

i want to know how to connect multiple USART (Each usart is connected to terminal) devices together to a single STM32L152RB so that one USART can communicate to another. This is the requirement
b - USART board.
This is clincher  (if u  do it). Connect 
    b1->b2. b2->b3, b3->b4 via uart.

```
 From B1 terra  term user tells

    mrc  -b=3
```

This stands for  "make remote call" on board3. 
     Then b1 via uart  communicate to b2, b2 to board 3.  Board 3 will make the
     switch on its LED to indicate its making call.

```
 src -b=3
```

will stop this remote call.

Comment: It's obviously not enough information in your question to answer it. Provide more details on setup you want to achieve. Some examples can help too. We need to know which board you use, your MCU, what prevents you to do what you want, is problem related to physical level or software. Also you can draw some picture illustrating what you are trying to achieve and attach it in your question.

Comment: Sorry for that... now edited...

Comment: Question still lacks the **actual** question: you want to know how to connect them physically? Or you already have them connected and you want to know how to write the proper code?

Comment: Actually i want to know both...

Comment: Please draw the picture with your setup, it's hard to understand an actual connections between your boards. Picture should contain: **1**. All USART boards. **2**. Your STM32 board (as I understood it is separate from those USART boards). **3**. PC (where serial console (terminal) program runs), if it exists in your setup. **4**. UART connections between all components. You can attach this picture to your original question (preferable) or just upload it to some image hosting site and share the link.